# Git list tracked files as of arbitrary commit

Tags: git

How can I list all tracked files as of a given commit instead of `HEAD`? Not the files that were added/modified in a commit, and not the files that are tracked in the current branch/commit.

I can get what I want by doing:

```sh
git checkout <commitish>
git ls-files --full-name
```

But I really can't do the checkout first. I tried:

```sh
git ls-files --full-name <commitish>
```

But that doesn't work. I've noticed that GitX and other tools can keep a tree view up to date when selecting arbitrary files; really that's what I'm trying to do.

---

**Edit**

Nevermind. I saw that I was using `git ls-files` instead of `git ls-tree`.

Comment: `git ls-tree -r thatcommit`, maybe with `--name-only`if you want that.

Comment: I tried that, but I get `error: unknown switch 'r'`. It also list the usage for `git-ls-files`, and `--name-only` isn't documented. I tried it anyway, but I get the same error.

Comment: `git ls-tree -r` *has* to work; if it does not, something is wrong with your Git installation (e.g., someone somehow overwrote the back end `git-ls-tree` binary with the `git-ls-files` binary).

Comment: Wow! I just saw that I was typing `git ls-files`, and you were saying `git ls-tree`!